# XQuery: How to get a specific value out of a tag?

Tags: return, xquery, key-value

Suppose we have this xml:

```
<question>
    <test id="1">
        <tag k="a" v="1"/>
        <tag k="a" v="2"/>
        <tag k="b" v="3"/>
    </test>
    <test id="2">
        <tag k="a" v="1"/>
        <tag k="a" v="4"/>
        <tag k="b" v="5"/>
    </test>
    <test id="3">
        <tag k="a" v="2"/>
        <tag k="a" v="6"/>
        <tag k="b" v="7"/>
    </test>
</question>
```

I would like to return all values v of test, if k = "a" AND v = "1", like this:

```
v="3"
v="5"
```

So far my approach:

```
for $i in //test
where ($i/tag[@k = 'a' and @v = '1'])
return $i/tag/@v
```

But this is not correct because thats the return:

```
v="1"
v="2"
v="3"
v="1"
v="4"
v="5"
```

Thank you for your help :)

Comment: Are you looking for the `tag/@v` where they *don't* have `@k='a' and @v="1"`, but do have siblings that do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably looking for something like

```
for $i in //test
where  ($i/tag[@k = 'a'][@v="1"])
return $i/tag[@k="b"]/@v
```

Answer (score 1):

Your criteria for selection was not exactly clear, but this returns what you expected:

```
for $i in //test
where $i/tag[@k = 'a' and @v = '1']
return $i/tag[not(@k = 'a' or @v = '1')]/@v
```

You could simplify and do this in a single XPath expression:

```
//test/tag[@k = 'a' and @v = '1']/tag[not(@k = 'a' or @v = '1')]/@v
```